# How to find printer error log on mac os x？

Tags: macos, logging, printing

I have a printer problem when I want to print a document, the printer queue says "backend failed" and then pause.

My computer is mac os x, version is sierra 10.12.6, and printer is Canon IR ADV4235 using smb protocol to access.
I have tried the following ways:

1. download the latest driver from Canon website, and reinstall the driver
2. remove the old printer
3. add new printer

but still the same problem.

So, I want to find the specific error, and I searched /var/log with keyword "backend" but no related result.
Could anyone provide some help?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Using the command `cupsctl --debug-logging`，I got more messages. The following error messages seem to be helpful.
`D [31/Jul/2017:13:47:44 +0800] [Job 25] PID 55276 (/usr/libexec/cups/backend/smb) crashed on signal 4.
...
D [31/Jul/2017:13:47:46 +0800] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [31/Jul/2017:13:47:46 +0800] [Job 25] PID 55275 (/Library/Printers/Canon/CUPS_Printer/Bins/capdftopdl) stopped with status 1.
I [31/Jul/2017:13:47:46 +0800] [Job 25] Backend returned status -4 (crashed)
D [31/Jul/2017:13:47:46 +0800] Discarding unused job-state-changed event...
I [31/Jul/2017:13:47:46 +0800] [Job 25] Printer stopped due to backend errors; please consult the error_log file for details.`

But, I tried to run `/usr/libexec/cups/backend/smb`, it was ok. I don't know if other parameters will cause it crashed.

Could anybody give me a hint?

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The log file you want is `/var/log/cups/error_log`, but by default it doesn't contain much info. You can increase the logging a great deal by turning on debug logging with `cupsctl --debug-logging` (and turn it off with `cupsctl --no-debug-logging`). In *macOS 10.12* this takes effect immediately, but in some older versions you needed to restart the cups daemon with `sudo launchctl stop org.cups.cupsd`.

Comment: The command can get more log on error_log, and I got more information. Thank you. But I still cannot find why, I will post the error message later.